# relation one_to_one: get a list of non-linked "belongs_to" entities

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, orm, one-to-many, one-to-one

I have an optimization question. I search how to use ActiveRecord to do a request to get all entities in a one_to_one or one_to_many which don't have any link.

I have:

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :model2
  ...
```

and

```
class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model1
  ...
```

If I want the list of all model2s non-link, I just have to do:

```
unlinked_model2s = Model2.where(:model1_id => nil)
```

But how I do the same for the model1s? I would have the list of all model1s which are not linked to a model2.

I tried many things, but the only way to make it works, is to to all the requests one by one, which is horrible:

```
unlinked_model1s = Array.new
Model1.all.each do |model1|
  unless model1.model2
    unlinked_model1s << model1
  end
end
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would require to write some SQL. By default AR supports only `inner join`, so you can't use `Model1.joins(:model2).where(...)`.

Looks like you can try `Model1.joins("left join model2s on (model2s.model1_id = model1s.id) ").where(:model2s => {:id => nil})`

or

`Model1.joins("left join model2s on (model2s.model1_id = model1s.id) ").where("model2s.id is NULL")`

Not sure this is syntactically (can't try the code :) ) correct, but hope this will give you an idea on how to accomplish your task.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Model1.joins("LEFT JOIN model2s ON (model2s.model1_id = model1s.id)").where(:model2s => {:model1_id => nil}) works perfectly! Thank you very much